# Undefined variable in Laravel view

Tags: select, view, laravel

I have tried to get a solution for this for hours and I really do not understand why it's not working.

routes.php

```
Route::get("/user/Session::get('theuser')/charname", array(
    'as' => 'profile-character',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@dropDownList'
    ));
```

ProfileController.php

```
public function dropDownList() {

$list = Character::lists('char_name', 'char_dynasty');

return View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);

}
```

profile.blade.php

```
 <div class="selected_char">

 <form action="{{ URL::route('profile-character') }}" method="get">

{{ Form::select('character', $character_options , Input::old('character')) }}


 </form>
</div>
```

This code throws me the error that the $character_options is undefined. I have read dozens of examples doing the same thing like me and working for them. Maybe this is Laravel 3?

Comment: What do you get if in `dropDownList()` you do `dd( Character::lists('char_name', 'char_dynasty') );` ?

Comment: Same error Undefined variable: character_options

Comment: If you get that error, then it suggests the controller method is not being executed, as a dd() in the controller method wouldn't even get so far as allowing the view to be rendered. As such, maybe the routing isn't working as expected (which sure explains how the Session::get() works in your route definition (it doesn't!) and instead some other route is hitting which calls that profile view without setting the `character_options` variable on the view? Do a `php artisan routes` on the command line and see what Laravel *thinks* your routes are. You might be surprised!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should not work on Laravel:

```
Route::get("/user/Session::get('theuser')/charname", array(
    'as' => 'profile-character',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@dropDownList'
    ));
```

You cannot have a call like `Session::get()` in your route, not as far as I know at least. Your route will work because it's a string valid for route, but that Session::get() will never really be used in the process.

If you literally hit the url:

```
http://localhost/user/Session::get('theuser')/charname
```

What you can have is something like:

```
Route::get("/user/{user}/charname", array(
    'as' => 'profile-character',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@dropDownList'
    ));
```

And do

```
public function dropDownList($user) {

    $list = Character::lists('char_name', 'char_dynasty');

    return View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);

}
```

Comment: I was surprised too when Route::get("/user/Session::get('theuser')/charname", array(
    'as' => 'profile-character',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@dropDownList'
    )); worked. I can't explain why either. But i still receive the error. I tried with public function dropDownList($user) public function dropDownList($character_options) and public function dropDownList($list). I have managed to get it work with {{ Form::select('character', Character::where('user_id', '=', Auth::User()->id )->lists('char_name', 'char_dynasty'), Input::old('character')) }} Is this a viable solution?

Comment: Edited to show you why it works, but it really don't. You should explain what you're trying to accomplish with this code, so people understands it better and try to help you.

Comment: I am trying to populate a drop down list with data from my database. I wanted to write a function inside my Controller and then return the result to my View. I guess I can't do that, but query my database directly from the view.

Comment: You *can* do what you're trying to, you just have some unrelated weird bug somewhere, don't give up hope! See my comment on your question for more possibilities and a debugging option.